# HTML table data (<td>) screen co-ordinates or frame in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview

I am using HTML to render some offline data in my application. I would be using the same HTML sources for different screen layouts, iPhone, iPad - landscape and portrait orientation. This means that the HTML table which I design for adding content would have to be stretched and shrunk accordingly.

I have some of the contents (text & pictures) which I can render by supplying it to HTML. But I also do have some complex content like MapView with some customisation which cannot be handled in HTML. So, I am planning to add the MapView as a subview on UIWebView exactly at the position where the `<td>` for map is assigned. By doing so, I guess I can change the position of subviews whenever there are any changes in the frame of webView.

So, I need a mechanism which would let me know the frame of the empty `<td>` which would be responsible for showing the mapView.

An example HTML extract of Table:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width = "100%">
This table data though assigned to width 100% would occupy maximum space which is left after assigning space for all table data columns of this row!
</td>
<td width = "80" height = "80">
This table data column is fixed with width and height of 80 pixels. This would be irrespective of the screen size but 80 px width and height would be assigned to this table data. We can use this fixed space for adding a MapView as subview if we get its frame with respect to UIWebView.
</tr>
</table>
```

My question here simply is, how to get the frame of second `<td>` with respect to UIWebView so that I can add MapView as subview exactly at the same location and also adjust the subView's location whenever UIWebView's frame changes.

**Edit:**
Just done small changes to the Java script of accepted answer to get the whole frame of  element:

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    var _height = 0;
    var _width = 0;
    _height += el.offsetHeight;
    _width += el.offsetWidth;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ))
    {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x , width: _width, height:_height};
}
```

Then in my WebView delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *x = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('MapViewLoc')).left"];
    NSString *y = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('MapViewLoc')).top"];
    NSString *width = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('MapViewLoc')).width"];
    NSString *height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('MapViewLoc')).height"];


    NSLog(@"X Y co-ordinates (%@, %@) & [%@, %@]", x, y, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this javascript code to your HTML page:

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Then in your code you can do this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   string x = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('td[1]') ).left"];
   string y = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getOffset( document.getElementById('td[1]') ).top"];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is td[1]? How would I refer to the td item of a particular row (tr)? Thanks for the answer, I am yet to implement and try it out.

Comment: In your example you show two td tags, so td[0] is the first one and td[1] is the second one. Probably a better idea is to give the specific td or tr an id like this: <td id="mapViewTD" width = "80" height = "80"> and then do: getOffset( document.getElementById('mapViewTD') ).left

Comment: How do I also modify the above code so that the whole frame of <td> is available? I mean, we now get the origin of the <td> but how do we also find out the width and height of the same?